# Rename label generated by bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the "Search" text content next to the filter input.
I use a table template and the search filter is generated, I want to change the **search** text because I want to use a different language.

Using development tool I found the div id is **user_data_filter** and it is under a label element.

I can change this by copying out the input form and changing the search text

```
$('#user_data_filter label').html('Keresés:  <input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder aria-controls="user_data">');
```

but after my change the filter doesn't work and I don't know why..

Here is the HTML:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Iskola Tábla</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
  <style>
  body
  {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   background-color:#f1f1f1;
  }
  .box
  {
   width:1270px;
   padding:20px;
   background-color:#fff;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
   border-radius:5px;
   margin-top:25px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container box">
   <h1 align="center">Iskola Tábla</h1>
   <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">
   <br />
    <div align="right">
     <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-info">Hozzáadás</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="alert_message"></div>
    <table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Ügyfél neve</th>
       <th>Termék</th>
       <th></th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function(){
  fetch_data();
  function fetch_data()
  {
   var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
   });
  }
 });
</script>
```

Can somebody help me to change the **search** text content with working filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These labels and controls are part of the datatables and are not available until initialized. You can use a callback function if you really want to continue with this approach:

```
var dataTable = $ ('#user_data').DataTable({
    "initComplete": function (settings, json){
        $('# user_data_filter label').html('Keresés: <input type = "search" class = "form-control input-sm" placeholder aria-controls="user_data">');
    }
});
```

However, If I understood you correctly, you would like to display the datatable in a different language. Therefore, instead of trying to reinvent the wheel, I would strongly recommend that you take a closer look at the many options the datatable already brings to you.

https://datatables.net/reference/option/language

https://datatables.net/manual/i18n

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine, was your `$('#user_data_filter label').html('...');` line put in the `$(document).ready` function? That worked for me.

If you'd like to make the replacement a little more dynamic, you could replace only the "Search" word. That code would look like this, and also be placed in the `$(document).ready` function.

```
var labelElem = $("#user_data_filter > label");
var newText = labelElem.html().replace("Search", "Keresés");
labelElem.html(newText);
```

[JSFiddle Example.](https://jsfiddle.net/PatTastic/1x6a6L2w/1/)